# Access environment variable in application.yml in a micronaut app

Tags: java, groovy, micronaut

I have a token in my server, stored in an environment variable called TOKEN_URL

I want to access this variable in the Micronaut's configuration yml like this:

```
bot:
  token:
    value: ${env.TOKEN_URL}
```

Is there a way to access my env in this file? (${env.TOKEN_URL} is NOT working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just `${TOKEN_URL}`?

For the documentation on this, check out the "Property value binding" section of the [micronaut docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried all possible combinations of environment and I just didn't need it!